# In Slick, how to set default value for updatetime?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-2.0

I saw the approach to assign current time to `createtime` when a row is inserted at:

http://queirozf.com/entries/scala-slick-dealing-with-datetime-timestamp-attributes

But is there a way to set the current time to `updatetime` when an existing row is updated?

Answer (score 0):

The link you indicated is a hack. It may work just the same way. Officially this feature is not supported right now https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/214